# Fancybox - New Items Working offline but not when uploaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, lightbox

I have looked through this for three days and I hope someone can help. My fancybox was working just fine. It was only until I just uploaded some new items to my portfolio that the images were no longer working.

If you go to my site, in the design images (http://www.kristinazach.com/designs.html) the fancy box works no problem, but then if we go to photos/family (http://www.kristinazach.com/photos_family.html), the most recent images I added (first 6) don't work but the rest do (because they are older). The thing I need help understanding is why do the old items work and the newer items I am having issues with when I haven't changed anything but the path to the image?

Hope someone can help me, as this is getting quite mind boggling and frustrating.

If anyone has any better lightbox gallery ideas I'm happy to take suggestions too.

Please and thank you!!!!!

Comment: New Images are missing from family folder `http://www.kristinazach.com/images/photos/family/family_34.jpg` this redirects to 404.

Comment: No... believe me. I wish it was something easy like that. I have all the images in the same folder organized in numerical order, and the size is the same for all of them.

Comment: If the image is present in the folder then http://www.kristinazach.com/images/photos/family/family_34.jpg should be accessible in browser just like other images. Also, check the file permissions of the new images.

Comment: Your images are missing or the path is wrong. Easily seen in the console.It is easy like that

Comment: Hey Guys! @Samir, I checked the permissions of the the new images vs the old images and those permissions are all the same. And Macsupport, I know the images I in the folder and the path is correct because everything is working offline, its just online thats not working. Is it possible there are some kind of permissions in dreamweaver that I could look for? Now I feel like I'm talking non-sense. But my thoughts are the problem is online somewhere.